# Script inside window opened by window.open() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I was trying to open a window where in i can do a process inside the opened windows using ajax. but my scripts doesn't work at all.

Here's my script so far on my main window

```
$('.tracker-window').on("click", function() {
      var newWindow  = window.open("/etrcontroller", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,top=500,left=900,width=400,height=400");
    });
```

And my code in my opened window

```
<script>

$(function () {  alert();   });

</script>
```

when I opened the window using the first script it opens up but it does not alert.

Can I ask for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: When you open the console in your new window, what's the error you are getting?

Comment: $ is not defined <--- this is the only error I'm getting so far.

Comment: Isn't it quite crucial to have jQuery loaded before it is used?

Comment: `$ is not defined` means that you didn't load jQuery in your new windows. A new window doesn't automatically have scripts from other windows, you have to load everything again. This also includes jQuery if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first make sure you added jquery**

Try your code inside `$( document ).ready()`

for example

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.tracker-window').on("click", function() {
      var newWindow  = window.open("/etrcontroller", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,top=500,left=900,width=400,height=400");
    });
});
```

and

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert('hello world');
});
```

Comment: `$` was not defined, and `$(function () {...})` is a valid and working shortcut to `$( document ).ready(function() {...})`.